# Integration tests for Docker container in Maven Project with Multiple Modules

Tags: java, docker, maven, integration-testing, fabric8

There is a project consisting of two jar artifacts (grpc services) that packaged into corresponding Docker containers
Each of them specifies root project as parent and included to parent project with pom packaging  as sub-modules
Both containers are built with fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin and have their own integration tests using failsafe plugin.

Is there possibility in Maven project model to create integration test for their integration?
Is it good practice to create a separate module (what packaging type to choose? pom or jar?) only for tests and specify two docker images only in run section of docker-maven-plugin configuration or there is a better way to do it? How to ensure that images were built if they are not artifacts in terms of Maven?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use https://testcontainers.org